# How do I add Eclipse C++ to Eclipse classic?

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have Eclipse Classic for my Java classes, and I have Visual Studio as well, but I'd much rather keep using Eclipse. Can anyone help?

I tried adding the addons from within Eclipse but it didn't work properly.

Comment: Classes as in University classes, not OOP classes. :P

Comment: Install new Software: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/kepler/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need the [Eclipse CDT project plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/).

Having said that, unless you need platform independence, don't give up on Visual Studio. For C/C++ Visual Studio is way, way, way better and faster than Eclipse. (IMHO).

Comment: I guess it does have about the same boot time. I wonder if there's an equivalent of Ctrl+Shift+F in Visual Studio 2010, I can't live without it. :P

Answer (score 13):

If you work with Windows, I suggest you use 2 different instances of Eclipse. As Eclipse is a portable app (no registry), it is easy to use 2 different instances, or more.

You can also go to Help -> Install new software, choose the Eclipse update site and then choose the C/C++ Development Tools package.

**Edit:** I have just seen LarsH's question. I should have added that the C/C++ Development Tools package is an Eclipse standard issue and can be added from official Eclipse update sites, like the Juno update site: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/ (it should already be in your update sites list if you are using Eclipse Juno). If everything else fails, you can even download the C/C++ tools here: http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php and install them yourself.

Comment: This may be helpful answer ... it would be more helpful if (1) you give us a hint why it's better to use 2 different instances (despite the cost of needing to remember which instance to launch, and other diminished integration); and (2) you provide a link to the Eclipse update site that you mean ... that could refer to many things.

Comment: I would rather say: why wouldn't you use different instances? I really dislike having my Eclipse cluttered with all kind of plugins. If some projects combine, for example, Java and C code, I can understand why you would want to use the same instance, but for completly differents projects, some with Java and some with C, I can't see any good reason to use the same instance. find the good instance is just a matter of shortcut naming.

Answer (score 2):

I dear myself to say, that seems unwise. As you get plugins and write quite a few projects, you will have increased load times. At least my personal preference is to use multiples instances of eclipse.

Link for c/c++-developers version of eclipse: ( [link](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/heliossr1) )

You can autoformat .net with `CTRL-A` and then `CTRL-K+F`. If you use Autohotkey you can create a script that is executed when you press `CTRL-SHIFT-F` and remap it to:

```
Send, {CTRLDOWN}a{CTRLUP}{CTRLDOWN}kf{CTRLUP}
```

I also had thought for a long time, that .net IDE designers where not mentally erudite enough to understand the importance of autoformat, to include it. I got so pissed, that I wrote one myself and ran it as external program. Only reacently I found out about `CTRL-K+F`.`:D`

Comment: Is it also relevant to worry about loading times when running on an SSD? It cuts loading times so drastically, that I'm sceptic as to whether its relevant to worry about increased loading times.